# Has unit test coverage been removed from Resharper 2020.1 release

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, code-coverage

Jsut installed Resharper Ultimate 2020.1 on a new machine and I noticed there is no longer a right click menu 'Cover Unit Tests' on an item in the Unit Test explorer window.

Can anyone confirm this feature has been removed from R#?

It was there in 2019.3.4 version

Comment: You have to select dotCover during installation, or there is never code coverage support. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Installation_Guide.html#

Comment: It is selected and installed.

Comment: Not sure what the 'Unit Test explorer window' you are referring to but the right click options are on the 'Unit Test Sessions' window (`ReSharper`->`Windows`->`Unit Test Sessions`)

Comment: Check you have dotCover in "ReSharper | Help | License Information" dialog and it is activated by a license. Then check that you have the dotCover node in "ReSharper | Options | dotCover" and it is enabled on "ReSharper| Options | Environment | Products & Features" page.